# How do I remove or turn off the errors displayed inline in the editor windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I turn off or remove these "tips" (seen on the right side of image) from the editor?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is controlled by the "Display diagnostics inline" option.  To turn it off go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced and toggle the control.

[image: Display diagnostics inline]